# Never-ending "maintenance in progress"

Tags: windows-8, action-center

My desktop PC (used primarily for development) has recently been telling me (via *Action Center*) that it needs to perform "maintenance". I allow it to do so, and hours later (I left it running overnight a couple of times) it is still reporting *Maintenance in progress*.

[image: Maintenance in progress]

Task manager reports no significant CPU or disk usage, and I have separately trimmed/defragmented my disks (a 256GB Samsung SSD and separate 1TB HDD).

Can anyone suggest what might be boing on?

Comment: you can stop the maintenance in the action center

Comment: @magicandre1981 - true, I can stop the maintenance, but then Action Center still reports that maintenance is required. My question is regarding what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This finally stopped when I updated to Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

when windows display the message that maintenance in progress it doesn't mean it's defragmenting your drive, there are several other process like computer scan through windows defender, check for risky program, updating-installing windows update or any Microsoft product update and many more..

Comment: So how does one find out what exactly the maintenance is doing?

Answer (score 1):

When my computer was in the long-running maintenance, I found settings/windows-update. and saw a message to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using windows 8.1, got the same notification but i finally disabled the auto maintenance thing.

Just go to search option and type in maintenance. Find the "change auto maintenance settings" then tick the "allow scheduled maintenance..." hit ok. (at this point it should be ok now.)

Re-do the steps but this time uncheck the "allow schedule...." if you do not want a maintenance schedule set.

That's it. the notification is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you doing a Windows Update and installing all the "necessary" security updates. In my experience, this is what I've had to do before the Automatic Maintenance thing started finishing when it runs, although I'm still skeptical about what does it do at all and why it should run everyday. I hope it's not defragmenting the SSD because that'd be too bad and totally useless.