# Never-ending 'Maintenance in progress' on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, action-center

On Windows 8.1, My action centre flag (telling me  'Maintenance in progress') won't stop or go away.  I've left it for two days now and it's still there.  There are no details and I've tried stopping it and starting it and have restarted the PC several times.  What is causing this?

The PC is only  weeks old.  I'm running an SSD and an SSHD, so any defragging should be minimal.

Any idea what is causing it or how I can stop it without disabling maintenance altogether?

**Edit: I was asked to move this answer to a new question because it was on a different operating system (8.1 not 8).  It was down-voted there, so I created this question with 8.1 clearly marked.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning on (or restarting) OneDrive synchronising. I'd disabled this to see if it was causing some stuttering in games and when I re-enabled it, the action flag disappeared immediately.

All other causes of the 'busy' clock-icon appearing are explained by clicking on it, in my experience.  The message in the pop-up details the work in progress.

Comment: Should this be an answer or a comment to your own question, Chandra?

Comment: @dude - Its an answer to his similar problem that somebody else had with [Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/677525/never-ending-maintenance-in-progress/873107?noredirect=1#comment1161709_873107) but he experienced the problem with `Windows 8.1` which of course is the reason its not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it's an answer to a question I had that I couldn't append to an answer list elsewhere: http://superuser.com/questions/677525/never-ending-maintenance-in-progress/873107#873107